# How can I expand $\sum _{m=1}^{n-1} \prod _{k=m+1}^n x_k x_m$ Is it an error?

Tags: polynomials

$n \geq  m\geq 1$

How can I expand this expression

$$\begin{align*}\sum _{m=1}^{n-1} \prod _{k=m+1}^n x_k x_m\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

[(1) is from the wiki's page](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%A6%E8%BE%BE%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86)

seems (2) is right for Vieta's formula?
$$\begin{align*}\sum _{m=1}^{n-1} \sum _{k=m+1}^n x_k x_m\end{align*}\tag{2}$$

for example $n=5$.

user64494's answer show a example that Maple did.

The expected answer maybe what the Vieta's formula shows.

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n-1}+x_{n}=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}} \\
\left(x_{1} x_{2}+x_{1} x_{3}+\cdots+x_{1} x_{n}\right)+\left(x_{2} x_{3}+x_{2} x_{4}+\cdots+x_{2} x_{n}\right)+\cdots+x_{n-1} x_{n}=\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n}} \\
\vdots \\
x_{1} x_{2} \ldots x_{n}=(-1)^{n} \frac{a_{0}}{a_{n}}
\end{array}\right.$$

---

I'm not sure whether the following two formulas are true. (***Are they wrong?***)

Though they are in wiki's page. But cannot be calculated by Mathematica or Maple directly.

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}} \\ \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \prod_{k=m+1}^{n} x_{m} x_{k}=\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n}} \\ \vdots \\ \Pi_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}=(-1)^{n} \frac{a_{0}}{a_{n}}\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}=(-1)^{1} \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}} \\ \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(\Pi_{k=m}^{m+1}\left(-x_{k}\right)\right)=(-1)^{2} \frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n}} \\ \sum_{m=1}^{n-2}\left(\Pi_{k=m}^{m+2}\left(-x_{k}\right)\right)=(-1)^{3} \frac{a_{n-3}}{a_{n}} \\ \vdots \\ \Pi_{k=1}^{n}\left(-x_{k}\right)=(-1)^{n} \frac{a_{0}}{a_{n}}\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: The asked sum of the products does not coinside with the second Vieta's formula.

Comment: @user64494 see edit.

Comment: @ HyperGroups: I submitted my comment after your edit.

Comment: @user64494 See the picture below, is it wrong?

Comment: @ HyperGroups: Yor notation is not correct as $x_m$ in the product $ \prod _{k=m+1}^n x_k x_m$  is multipled $n-m$ times. If $n=m$, this product has no sense. Also $$n := 5; sum(x[m]*expand(product(x[k], k = m+1 .. n)), m = 1 .. n-1) $$ produces $$x[1]*x[2]*x[3]*x[4]*x[5]+x[2]*x[3]*x[4]*x[5]+x[3]*x[4]*x[5]+x[4]*x[5] .$$

Comment: Please give the coordinates of the Wiki page you refer to.

Comment: I think the Chinese edition of Wiki gives wrong formulas: compare with [the English one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: @user64494 The bad thing is the English one does not give the Summation and Product Notation.

Comment: @ HyperGroups : If you carefully read the article in the English edition Wiki, you will see the ones. I definitely end the discussion.

Comment: @user64494 Ok, glad to discuss with you. Here is a similar question I asked in [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30202/is-the-formula-sum-m-1n-1-prod-k-m1n-x-k-x-m-wrong-in-the-wikis)